# Can you grab a file with PHP through a form with $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; action?

Tags: php, forms, file-upload, email-attachments

I have an email attachment form that is working fine when the `<form action="processingtheformfile.php">` is sent to another PHP file to process.

However, when I try to implement the same idea to a form that is simply `<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">` and then use a

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
$tmp_name = $_FILES['filename']['tmp_name'];
$type = $_FILES['filename']['type'];
$name = $_FILES['filename']['name'];
$size = $_FILES['filename']['size'];
```

before the HTML of file, the attachment ends up being `noname.txt` everytime, regardless of file type.

Is this because the `$_FILES` cannot work on a `<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>` action, or should I look elsewhere for my dilemna?

Pray this makes sense....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Forms that are used for uploading files need to have `enctype="multipart/form-data"` to make it work. Here's an example:

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="">
```

Although you report that the first form works properly, I'm not sure it works reliably in all cases. Make sure it has this value for `enctype` so it'll work properly.

Comment: HAHA! So simple, and yet I overlooked it.  The previous form DID in fact contain this, but the new one did not.  Spot on!  Many thanks!